# The method and() is undefined for the type HttpSecurity

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Im trying to follow this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1537#issuecomment-55609582) that is basically a bit of code to actually invalidate de login on angular.js.

I get "The method and() is undefined for the type HttpSecurity"

This is my part of my [Code](https://gist.github.com/cristiandley/8a1eace26de1313121a9) (line 89):

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic()

        .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/error" , "/error.html")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            /*.permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()*/

        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()

        .and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())

        .and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)

        .and() /* HERE IS WHERE I GET THE WARNING */
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl("/expired")
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());


    }

    ...more code here

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addFilterAfter()` already returns an instance of `HttpSecurity` so you can just call `sessionManagement()` on it without calling `and()` first.

Comment: if i do that i keep getting `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/scripts/angular.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled`

Comment: That's a different error. You should ask a new question for it.